# Python intermittent OpenSSL error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, openssl, urllib3

I'm getting an intermittent error on my production Django website (running under UWSGI) when trying to use the kubernetes client library. The error seems to be urllib3, or perhaps OpenSSL. The strange thing is, I can simply restart my server and the problem goes away, but only temporarily. After a while I start seeing this error again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 353, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data)           
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is extremely difficult to troubleshoot, because restarting the server makes the problem go away for a few hours. I added some extra logging to the `load_verify_locations` function in `urllib3/util/ssl_.py` to see what file it's trying to open. The `ca_certs` argument is passing in a temp file, `/tmp/tmp2xng8a6e`. The other two arguments are `None`.

So, why a temp file, and why is it missing? Is there a reason why the temp file would get deleted, or why urllib3 might not be creating the temp file in the first place?

Here's the full exception with traceback:

```
Aug 20 10:36:05 ERROR django.request: Internal Server Error: /code/projects/test-project/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 353, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/views.py", line 67, in ide
    utils.init_workspace(project)
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/utils.py", line 252, in init_workspace
    get_user_storage_resource(project.user).apply()
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/utils.py", line 79, in apply
    responses.append(item.apply())
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/utils.py", line 221, in apply
    if self.exists:
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/utils.py", line 165, in exists
    self._call('read')
  File "/srv/hive/src/hive/ide/utils.py", line 152, in _call
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 18854, in read_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim
    (data) = self.read_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 18945, in read_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 345, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 176, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 366, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 241, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 214, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 76, in request
    method, url, fields=fields, headers=headers, **urlopen_kw
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 97, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/srv/hive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ide-ideresourcegroup-207977-dbdb0faf.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces/ide/persistentvolumeclaims/workspace-storage-5p2lm91r (Caused by SSLError(FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'),))
```